# checked checkbox in gridview will update the gridview after button is clicked

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

**here's the explanation:**

1. I have two tables in my database, tblDiscount and tblDaily tables. they are interrelated through tenantId column.
2. I have a query in sql that creates another column named as GSC where it sums up the value of cash, charge, gift and discount in tbldaily table.the result is passed to a sqldatasource in asp.net where it is used to load the gridview.
3. I put a checkbox column in the gridview, the condition is when the user checks checkbox/es gridview and click the button, the gridview must reload and update the GSC column deducting the discount value from the previous sum of (cash+charge+gift+discount). the checking of checkbox acts as inserting a value in the tblDiscount table, unchecking those on the other hand will delete the record in the said table.

**what i want to achieve:**

1. when the user searches for a tenant and a specific date (example: search for McDonalds , transaction date: 01/01/2014 - 01/31/2014), the gridview will load the gridview as is with the created column : GSC, summing up the cash, credit, gift and discount values. When he/she checks the 01/01/2014 - 01/05/2014 checkboxes rows, and clicks the recompute button:

   a.  the system will insert data in tblDiscount table (tbldiscount columns are: dates, tenantID).

   b. the gridview will then recompute the gridview - GSC COLUMN deducting the discount value from it
2. When the user unchecks the checked dates, it will do the opposite:

   a. will delete the data in tbldiscount

   b. the gridview will recompute again the GSC column - adding the discount value.

The checkbox in the gridview and recompute button act like the tool to insert and delete data in tblDiscount and signal summing and deducting the discount from the GSC (Gross Sales Chargeable) IN THE GRIDVIEW DATA.

How to do it?

**Here's the code that i started:**

```
protected void btnRecompute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int counter = 0;
        double newGSC = 0;
        string oDisc = "", gsc = "", oDiscFinal = "", gscFinal = "", answer = "";
        con.Open();

        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdDSTR.Rows)
        {


            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCheckRow") as CheckBox);
                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                    oDisc = (row.Cells[7].Text);
                    oDiscFinal = (oDisc.Replace(",", string.Empty));

                    gsc = (row.Cells[10].Text);
                    gscFinal = (gsc.Replace(",", string.Empty));

                    newGSC = Convert.ToDouble(gscFinal) - Convert.ToDouble(oDiscFinal);



                }

            }

        }
}
```

what i started there is actually extract the value of GSC AND DISCOUNT COLUMN of the checked checkbox and subtract GSC from DISCOUNT, and the difference will be used to update the database, but that is not possible because GSC is not an actual column in the tblDaily , it is just a computed or self made column.

**main goal or question, how to insert data in tblDiscount based on what dates are checked in checkbox then recompute the GSC column deducting the discount value from it, and vice versa when it is unchecked**

**updated:**

```
      IF EXISTS (select * from tbldiscount
            where date between '02/01/2014' and '02/28/2014'
            and tenantcode = 'OHBUFF11')

            BEGIN
            select ....
        convert(varchar,cast(((sum(a.cash) + SUM(a.charge) + SUM(a.gift)) - (SUM(a.surcharge))) as money),1) as GSC 
    ...
where (a.date between '02/01/2014' and '02/28/2014') and b.tenantcode = 'OHBUFF11'

            END



            ELSE
            BEGIN
             select ....
        convert(varchar,cast(((sum(a.cash) + SUM(a.charge) + SUM(a.gift)+ SUM(a.other)) - (SUM(a.surcharge))) as money),1) as GSC 
    ...
where (a.date between '02/01/2014' and '02/28/2014') and b.tenantcode = 'OHBUFF11'
            END
```

On my updated remarks, I am trying do test my query in mssql, using IF EXIST QUERY, I am to test if discount table has a data, if true it will go to the first option where in discount values are not part of the GSC summation, otherwise it will go to the option of adding it to the GSC.

**LIMITATION FOUND: How to determine ONLY the checked checkbox / dates available only in the tblDiscount?**

Thanks for advance sharing of your logical idea on hwo to do it